# IndexError: tuple index out of range in Turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

**IndexError: tuple index out of range in Turtle module**
**here is my code**

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()
s.bgcolor("black"), t.speed(0)

col = ("yellow", "red", "pink", "cyan", "light", "green", "blue")

for i in range(150):
    t.pencolor(col[186])
    t.circle(198-1/2, 99)
    t.lt(90)
    t.circle(199-1/3, 98)
    t.lt(60)
s.exitonclick()
```

Comment: `col[186]` is for sure out of range, you have only 7 elements in the tuple

Comment: I need all those colors how can I get it, sir?

Comment: Make sure there's at least 187 colors in the tuple, then it'll work. If you need lots of colors, probably use RGB, HSL or hex rather than a giant tuple of string literals though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cycle through that list of colors, you've a few options.  One option would be to use `cycle` from the `itertools` library.  A simple option is to use the modulus operator (%) in combination with your iteration variable and the length of your colors list:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COLORS = ['yellow', 'red', 'pink', 'cyan', 'green', 'blue']

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

for i in range(150):
    turtle.pencolor(COLORS[i % len(COLORS)])
    turtle.circle(198, 99)
    turtle.lt(90)
    turtle.circle(199, 98)
    turtle.lt(60)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```